# Multi tenant Daemon office 365 app registration,Access Certificate from Key Vault using tenant other than installation tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-keyvault, office365api, office365-apps

I am developing a multi-tenant Office 365 daemon that requires access to user calendars.

I have successfully registered in the company tenant (Tenant1) AD that has deployed this app using certificates and I am able to get access tokens.

Now I created a separate AAD tenant (Tenant 2) and logged in to daemon app using administrator account of Tenant 2, it prompted the Admin Consent screen and I provided consent.

Now, I want to store certificate in azure key vault. Since azure key vault is tied to Tenant1, I am getting errors when Tenant2 tries to get token. Any ideas on how to proceed with this? Am I going against the recommendations of using Key Vault

Comment: You still need another service principal in tenant 1 to access the key vault .See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application) .

Comment: Thats correct. Key challenge is to access it from Tenant2